# Use Meteor Client Sided Libraries in webpack only without meteor server

Tags: webpack, meteor

We are migrating away from a huge meteor project because the meteor build environment is way too slow. We are having a kind of big client code base which uses meteor. In the last few months, we have developed a new version of the app that does not use meteor, however we are now at the place where we need to run legacy and new side by side.

we therefor need a way to use meteor libraries (DDP, Mongo, Subscriptions, Tracker, etc.) inside of a standalone webpack project.

For most of the code, the packet `@socialize/react-native-meteor` was enough, however we now have added some of the legacy ui code and figured out that there are quite a few things that don't work. (e.g. Subscription to some Collections with custom subscription parameters, etc.)

Is there any other official way to use the `meteor/meteor`,  `meteor/mongo`, etc. packets from a non-meteor project?

Comment: I don't think there is anything official. If I had to lead this project, I would start with DDP. Everything else follows from there, and DDP by itself is a pretty simple protocol. So as soon as you have a custom client-side interpreter for that, you should be able to build all these meteor features (subscriptions, tracker) just based on react (useState, useEffect, etc.).

Comment: The goal is not to change the legacy UI code. It uses the Meteor Packages with Minimongo, Meteor Calls, Subscriptions, Reactive Tracker, etc. However we cannot use the meteor packages when we are building it without the meteor dev-environment and the meteor packages code have very strange assumptions and circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you mention Webpack, I assume you would like to keep existing Meteor app for backend, but abandon it for your new frontend ?

As far as I know there is no gateway or compatibility between Meteor packages & webpack/npm world. I wouldn't reproduce pub/sub mechanism & ddp protocol since it would be too much work, for hazardous results. The less effort and more stable solution would be to redefine your api layer.

I see two options :

1. Convert your publications & methods to `REST` endpoints. This can be done by using package such as [simple:rest](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publications-as-rest). Meteor team talks about it in their [documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publications-as-rest)
2. Introduce a `GraphQL` layer in your architecture. You can find a very good example by cloning [Vulcan](https://docs.vulcanjs.org/) project. It would be a great source of inspiration for your needs.

By adopting one of these solutions, you could then be able to create a Meteor free frontend, using `Next` or anything else that suits your requirements. This new frontend app will dialog with Meteor via `REST` or `GraphQL` API.

Your new front-end will need a library like `react-query` to add some abstraction and / or state management library such as `redux`. With these two, I think you can achieve what was done in legacy front app with `meteor/mongo`, Subscriptions, Tracker, and so.

I give here references related to React since this it's the only library I know, but this logic would remain the same with Vue or Svelte.

Comment: we are migrating backend and frontend. While the legacy meteor backend is stable and rarely changes, we are developing a new frontend and a new backend (Nest+GraphQL). We need to develop the old frontend with the new AND old backend without changes to the legacy frontend for making it work with the legacy backend again.  === The goal is to just improve frontend development with a new build environment that doesnt crash and is slow because of problems in the meteor build environment